# Prove that a simple path in a graph exists, if a path exists

Tags: graph-theory, path-connected

I learned that a simple path is a path p = $v_0,...,v_m$ with each $v_i \neq v_{i+1}$ with i $\in [m]$ and its a closed path/cycle, if $v_0 = v_m$, so the last node of the path is the same as the beginning.

Now I came across the statement: "In a simple graph exists a simple path between the nodes u and v, if there is a path between u und v."

But that path could also be a loop, if u = v, which is per definition not a simple path.

So why is this statement true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u=v$, then the sequence "$u$" is a simple $u,v$-path with length $m=0$.

(Note that usually, what you are calling a "path" is called a "walk", and what you are calling a "simple path" is just called a "path"; a closed walk with no repeated vertices except the first and last is called a "cycle".)

Comment: If the definitions are not worded very carefully, it might seem that a walk of length zero is a closed walk. I believe there is no such thing as a closed walk (or circuit or cycle) of length zero, while a closed walk (or cycle) of length one would consist of one vertex and one edge which is a loop. Have I got that right or wrong, or is this one of those things that varies from author to author?

Comment: This is an edge case that will vary from author to author simply because many people wouldn't think about it. But I would say that a walk of length zero *is* a closed walk, but *is not* a cycle (or simple cycle), even though it meets all the other qualifications for a cycle.

Comment: (We want it to be a closed walk, because it's the identity element for the group of closed walks going through that vertex. But we don't want it to be a cycle, because we want trees to be acyclic.)